# Spurious '-' text with epslatex and multiplot

Tags: gnuplot

The following gnuplot snippet generates a multiplot showing six plots of data ported via stdin, but the special filename '-' used is also printed on the output:

```
set term epslatex color
set output 'mwe.tex'
set multiplot layout 3,2 scale 1,1 columnsfirst
set xrange [-3.1415:3.1415]
set yrange[-1.0:1.0]
set cbrange [-1:1]
set size ratio -1.0
set palette rgb 33,13,10
unset colorbox
plot '-' with image
-3.1416 -1.00 0.00
-3.1089 -1.00 0.00
 (...)
e
(...)
unset multiplot
```

(The 'plot' command and what follows until and including 'e' is repeated six times with different input before the unset multiplot command.)

The output is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfUWE.png). The special filename '-' must be included in the plot command to plot inline data, but it should not be shown in the resulting plot. How to avoid this behavior?

The problem persists when using the 'standalone' term option with epslatex, but it does not show up when using other terminals.

I use gnuplot 4.6 patch 2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried `plot '-' with image notitle` or a line before the plot command `set key noautotitle` ?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the StackOverflow rule "no answer in the comments", here again as answer. Also check `help key` and the options there.

Try:

```
set key noautotitle
```

or

```
plot '-' with image notitle
```